# JUnit - how to use both TestCase AND TestResult in test?

Tags: java, class, junit

In order to use JUnit's `TestCase` methods such as `setUp()` and `tearDown()`, I have to have my test class `extend TestCase`.

In order to user JUnit's `TestResult` methods such as `addFailure()` and `addError()`, I have to have my test class `extend TestResult`.

Java does not allow for multiple inheritances, so how do I gain access to both of these (or more) classes in my tests?

OR: am I misunderstanding the purpose of the `TestResult` class, and this isn't something I should be doing?

Because I would imagine that I should be able to test an assertion (or other test) inside a `try` block for example, then `catch` and subsequently `addError` the caught exception.

Comment: What ancient version of JUnit are you using? You don't need to derive from TestCase since JUnit 4 or so; you just tag the test methods with the `@Test` annotation. Add `@Before` and `@After` methods for setup before each test, use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` to run code once for the whole class.

Comment: For testing exceptions, declare the test with `@Test(expected=SomeException.class)`.

Comment: You can use assertions in try block as well. Also take a look at AssertJ-it has nice way of testing exceptions.

Comment: So it appears I was going off an ancient tutorial whose examples still worked somehow that led me astray.